# Question about axiom schema of specification and notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I have a question related to axiom schema of specification and set notation.

Now my specific question goes like this.

> Let $X = \{a,b\}$ be given ($a \neq b$). Define $f: \mathcal{P}(X) \to X$ as $f(\emptyset) = a$, $f(\{a\}) = b$, $f(\{b\}) = a$, $f(\{a,b\}) = a$. Now consider the set (written informally)
> $$ S = \{f(A) \in X: f(A) \notin A\}. $$
> Is $a \in S$?

My reasoning is that using axiom schema of specification, $S = \{ x \in X : \exists A \big( x=f(A) \land A \in \mathcal{P}(X) \land f(A) \notin A \big) \}$. Since $ f(\emptyset) = a \notin \emptyset $, $a \in S$. Although $f(\{a,b\}) = a \in \{a,b\}$, I don't think this gives the contradictory result $a \notin S$. To say $a \notin S$ (in other words, $a \in X \setminus S$), we have to check

$$ \lnot \exists A(x=f(A) \land A \in \mathcal{P}(X) \land f(A) \notin A) \iff \forall A (x \neq f(A) \lor A \notin \mathcal{P}(X) \lor f(A) \in A) $$

Since $A = \emptyset$ gives $a = f(\emptyset)$, $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, $f(\emptyset) = a \notin \emptyset$, I think one cannot conclude $a \notin S$.

I'm very confused. Is $S$ just an ill-defined set? Any comments are appreciated

Comment: IMO, you are right. We have that $f(\emptyset)=a$ and $a \notin \emptyset$. Bit we have also $f(\{ a,b \})=a$ and $a \in \{ a,b \}$.

Comment: The fact that the function $f$ has the same output ($a$) for two different inputs does not contradicts the definition of *function* (that rules out: two different outputs for the same input).

Comment: So, in conclusion: $a \in S$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the comment. So the definition of $S$ is still valid (although written informally)?

Comment: I agree with your "rewriting": $S = \{ a \mid \exists A (A \in \mathcal P(X) \land a=f(A) \land a \notin A) \}$.